# list of lists of data structure - how do i access with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

i have been given a c# program from a software manufacturer that accesses a file and gives me a list of lists of datastructures

```
List<List<dataPt_struct>> RasterSet = new List<List<dataPt_struct>>();
```

this gives me a list of "indexes" something like

```
RasterSet Count = 100
[0]Count = 400
[1]Count = 411
```

and so on.  inside those i have another list of "indexes" which contain the actual data structure

```
[0]
   [X] 
   [Y] 
   [Z] 
...
[399]
   [X]
   [Y]
   [Z]
```

so now i need to access the X,Y,Z portion of the datastruct inside the list of lists .  For example, is it possible to use LINQ to say

```
if (RasterSet[i] >= 0 && Rasterset[i] =< 10)
RasterSet[i].Average(z=> z.Z);
```

to give me a an average of all the Z values that are contained in the "indexes" [0] to [10], each index of which has hundreds or thousands of secondary indexes, each of which has [x][y][z] values?

edit:  i've cobbled together a double foreach that works by making a normal list from the complex structure and then using normal linq on that list.  i'd still love to get the whole thing in one go.  thanks everyone for the suggestions

Comment: If I am not wrong then, You can use SelectMany function and then apply average function on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the total average:

```
var average = RasterSet.SelectMany(x => x).Average(x => x.Z);
```

To get the average of the sub lists from Index 0-10, do this:

```
var average = RasterSet.GetRange(0, 10).SelectMany(x => x).Average(x => x.Z);
```

Comment: unfortunately i get an error (does not contain a definition for Z and no extension method....).  I think it's because the datastruct is still one list down.

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be fine now :-)

Comment: cheers mate, that works pretty good, and a simple and understandable change.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you need:

```
RasterSet.SelectMenu(rs => rs.Take(11)).Average(x => x.Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following code

```
RasterSet.Take(10).SelectMany(x => x.Z).Average();
```

You can also use Skip() function if you want to do the paging

Answer (score 0):

Something like this mey be...

```
var avg = from i in RasterSet
      let innerRasterSet = RasterSet[i]
      where i > 0 && i <= 10
      select innerRasterSet.Average(z=> z.Z);
```

Comment: i like this syntax but i'm getting a "cannot convert from Generic.List to int" error with i

Comment: Your truth, my bad.