# linq count (replace foreach and/or general speed up)

Tags: c#, linq

related to a [question I asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654590/list-of-lists-of-data-structure-how-do-i-access-with-linq) (and got a great answer for)

i have a list roi and an array[][]avg.  the list contains an index (of course), each index contains X,Y,Z values in a data structure

i've gotten what i need with a terrible foreach (terribly slow!) and i'm wondering if there is an obvious way to speed this up

```
for (int i = 0; i < raster_max; i++)
        {
            foreach (var sublist in RasterSet)
            {
                foreach (var dataPt in sublist)
                {
                    if (RasterSet.IndexOf(sublist) == i)
                    {
                        if (dataPt.Y >= Convert.ToSingle(textBox7.Text) && dataPt.Y <= Convert.ToSingle(textBox6.Text))
                        {

                                test[0][i] = dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i];
                                if (dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i] <= tA)
                                {
                                    corrA[i]++;
                                }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

RasterSet is an indexed List of Lists of DataStructures where dataPt is the final datastructure i need to access.  raster_max is the length of RasterSet.  avgbias[][] is the dataset i generated by using the linked question assistance.

Comment: Can you add sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Fix your ) in the if statement. Also this for loop doesn't make sense i> total ?!

Comment: posted too quick.  thanks.  added some data, hope it helps clarify.

Comment: @ferday what is value of total, you have error in for declaration.

Comment: goodness, my sign was backwards!  still get a result, but still not the right one.  i'm amazed i got a result before, nice catch

Comment: maybe you wanted `roi.Count(x=> (x.Z - 0.5) < 0)` (x instead of r in the predicate)?

Comment: still no good, don't know why.  changed questions completely

Comment: Under the hood a LINQ statement also has to iterate over the whole list. So LINQ doesn't help to improve performance just by using it. One big problem I see is that in your most inner loop you call `Convert.Tosingle()` each and every time. Better do the conversion only once before looping.

Comment: Also, if you have a performance problem, measure it. In Visual Studio there is a performance profiler, which helps to find the bottleneck.

Comment: Probably you could parallelize this thing by using the *Task Parallel Library*. But especially things like `i++` are evil there and needs (maybe) a complete rethink of the algorithm.

Comment: What is the *exact* type of `RasterSet`?

Comment: thanks Oliver.  Profiler tells me this is indeed the bottleneck.  I'll clean up the convert call, i've been trying to rethink the method but this is the first working iteration so far.

Comment: @ Gert Arnold:  RasterSet = List<List<dataPt_struct>> RasterSet = new List<List<dataPt_struct>>();

Comment: Actually, you don't really use `sublist` anywhere. What is it supposed to do? It doesn't play a role in the inner loop where the real stuff happens.

Comment: it's the only way i know how to get into the data structure at the bottom of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach (var sublist in RasterSet)
     {
        foreach (var dataPt in sublist)
        {
           if (RasterSet.IndexOf(sublist) == i)
           {
           ...
```

This looks strange.
Isn't this the same as

```
   single s7 = Convert.ToSingle(textBox7.Text);
   single s6 = Convert.ToSingle(textBox6.Text);
   for (int i = 0; i < raster_max; i++)
   {
       var sublist = RasterSet[i]

        foreach (var dataPt in sublist)
        {
            if (dataPt.Y >= s7 && dataPt.Y <= s6)
            {
                test[0][i] = dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i];
                if (dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i] <= tA)
                {
                    corrA[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could be, i'll try that out.  certainly looks nice, thanks for the suggestion.  edit: gives me the same results and is slightly faster.  thanks!

Comment: I wonder if  there be any benefit of assigning avgbias[6][i] to a temp variable outside the inner loop?

Answer (score 1):

Best optimizations I can see:

```
single s7 = Convert.ToSingle(textBox7.Text);
single s6 = Convert.ToSingle(textBox6.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < raster_max; i++)
{
    foreach (var sublist in RasterSet)
    {
        if (RasterSet.IndexOf(sublist) == i)
        {
            foreach (var dataPt in sublist)
            {
                if (dataPt.Y >= s7 && dataPt.Y <= s6)
                {
                    test[0][i] = dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i];
                    if (dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i] <= tA)
                    {
                        corrA[i]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, you don't do anything useful with this `RasterSet`, at least not in the code you show. The only thing that seems to matter is the number of sublists it contains. Well, is so, and since the other answers don't mention it, let me show you what I think the ultimate optimization would be:

```
var lowerBound = Convert.ToSingle(textBox7.Text);
var upperBound = Convert.ToSingle(textBox6.Text);

if (dataPt.Y >= lowerBound && dataPt.Y <= upperBound)
{
    raster_max = Math.Min(RasterSet.Count, raster_max);
    for (int i = 0; i < raster_max; i++)
    {
        test[0][i] = dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i];
        if (dataPt.A - avgbias[6][i] <= tA)
        {
            corrA[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that also the range check for `dataPt.Y` can be done right at the beginning. If `dataPt.Y` is out of bounds the loop doesn't even have to start.